# Autofac Multiple Lifetime Scopes with single Container

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm trying to figure out a work around for using multiple lifetimes with a single Container.

The problem is related to `InstancePerRequest()` implementation.

There is an application based on WebAPI with custom WebHandler, so Autofac can not define whether the `LifetimeScope` is initialized or disposed. So i can not use basic `InstancePerRequest()`. I decided to implement semi-custom `InstancePerRequest()` according to [Autofac documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#implementing-custom-per-request-semantics)

The Autofac registration looks like this:

```
...
private static IContainer Container;

private static void RegisterServices()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.Register((c, p) => new CustomClass(p.Named<List<int>>("codes"), p.Named<User>("user")))
            .InstancePerRequest();

    Container = builder.Build();
}

public static ILifetimeScope BeginLifetimeScope()
{  
    return Container.BeginLifetimeScope(new[] { MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag });
}
...
```

`MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag` is required in Autofac Custom per-request semantics according to [this article](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#implementing-custom-per-request-semantics) (point 2)

So i manually create `LifetimeScope`:

```
... // AutofacHelper.BeginLifetimeScope() is implemented above
using (var lifetimeScope = AutofacHelper.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    result = InvokeRequest(request.Api, context);
} 
...
```

The problem is that there are as many `LifetimeScope`'s as requests. And the scope i need begins far away from the code, where i need to access it. I need to have access to the current scope from anywhere.

I guess i have to tag every `LifetimeScope` with `HttpContext.Current` and that would be unique enough to define which scope i need to use.

But how do i do that? Implementing `BeginLifetimeScope()` with parameter `new[] { MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag, HttpContext.Current }` leads to exception as it can not find requested scope.

Is there a way to define which scope is being used in current request? Using my custom unique tag for example? `ILifetimeScope` has implementation for parent scopes only. Is there a reason for not implementing child scopes so i could take them according to `HttpContext.Current`?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have is actually totally correct.

> The problem is that there are as many LifetimeScope's as requests

That's not a problem, that's how it works. Even into ASP.NET Core today, and not even just Autofac - instance per request means one lifetime scope per request.

You have a couple of options to track the lifetime scope.

First, you can inject `ILifetimeScope` into any constructor and the thing that gets injected is the lifetime scope that owns the object. So if you have something registered `InstancePerRequest` then you can just add an `ILifetimeScope` constructor parameter... and it gets the request scope.

Second, you can always store the lifetime scope *in `HttpContext.Current`* when you create it.

```cs
using (var lifetimeScope = AutofacHelper.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    HttpContext.Current.Items["RequestLifetimeScope"] = lifetimeScope;
    result = InvokeRequest(request.Api, context);
}
```

Then if you absolutely must get that scope for, like, service location, you can do it from the current context.

```cs
var scope = (ILifetimeScope)HttpContext.Current.Items["RequestLifetimeScope"];
var x = scope.Resolve<IService>();
```

If you want more pointers on where you can store the scope, how you can access it... or even if you want to use some of the built-in helpers, I'd check out [the source for the Autofac WebAPI integration](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi). You also may be interested in looking at how Web API itself moves the request scope around - it [stores the scope along with the inbound request message](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/6248bfd24c31356e75a31c1b1030d4d96f669a6a/src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs#L56) so you can call `message.GetDependencyScope()` and get the current lifetime scope. You could do something similar.

If you're using an OWIN pipeline, there is [OWIN integration for WebAPI, too](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi.Owin) that might give you some ideas about how things are hooked up.